# Application of Exponential Functions to Radioactive Decay

Tags: calculus

I'm doing a project in Calc 1 and I honestly don't even know where to start with this one. I'm not looking for the answer just a good nudge in the right direction.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYblU.jpg]

This is the first time I have had to do anything like this so I'm honestly not even sure what is being asked.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Should have added the link for the second problem. 
[Link to the Graph for number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sej0g.jpg)

Comment: This is a standard Calc 1 class? Whew!! ... Here's a way to get started on part a. If you start with an amount $A(-t)$ at time $-t$ and go to time $0$, a certain fraction decays to give you $A(0)$. Because the time from $0$ to $t$ is the same, that same fraction of $A(0)$ will decay to give you $A(t)$. So $A(0)=kA(-t)$ and $A(t)=kA(0)$ (whatever $k$ is). Now what do you know about $A(0)$?

Comment: So as -t approaches 0, A(-t) approaches A(0) which is 1. 

Now because the absolute value is the same, t and -t have the same distance to travel to 0.

t is coming from the opposite direction, but it is approaching 1. You get 1 by combining the reciprocals?

Comment: No limits involved here :)

Comment: for a) I would suggest to think it in this way: if in going from 0 to 1 sec. the substance reduces to $90$%, how much it was 1 sec before 0?

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the help.